# Name for function projecting a 3D point to the surface of aligned sphere

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, terminology

Let there be a 3D point $\mathbf{P} = \begin{bmatrix} X & Y & Z\end{bmatrix}^{\top}$ and a sphere $\mathcal{S}$ with radius $r$ and centroid at the origin, everything expressed w.r.t the same coordinate frame. We define a function $f(\cdot)$ that projects a 3D point to the surface of $\mathcal{S}$ along the line joining the the 3D point to the origin, i.e., $f(\mathbf{P}) = \mathbf{Q}$ such that:
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{Q} = \arg \min_{\mathbf{Q}} \| \mathbf{P} - \mathbf{Q} \| \qquad \text{s.t.:} \quad \mathbf{Q} \in \mathcal{S}, \quad\|\mathbf{Q}\| = r
\end{equation}

My *question* is: please let me identify if there is a standard name for such a function $f$. This is perhaps something like a 'projection to a sphere', but I wonder if there's something following convention.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding something, isn't the function just given by dividing by the norm of $P$ and multiplying by $r$?

Comment: I would refer to $f$ as “the function that norms a vector to length $r$”.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese, yes sure it is, just looking for a concise terminology, preferably shorter than 'given by dividing by the norm of P and multiplying by r', if it exists at all. And also without having to define it afresh. Thanks.

Comment: I am starting to think there is none.